# mutate new column if duplicate id uniqueID

Tags: r

I have a dataframe,

```
data1 <- data.frame(ADD=c(15366,"ABC_65273","ABC_87536","ABC_43756",63854,"ABC_18385","ABC_87536",11111,"BCG_61773","ARV_44634","CAN_46926","TXA_47268",64574,"PIP_49229","BCG_57151","ARV_49049","CAN_45493","TXA_49401",45623,"PIP_41411","BCG_63402","CAN_45493","CAN_40584","TXA_51037",63523,"PIP_47714","BCG_57337","ARV_57727","CAN_45493","TXA_58079","PIP_43069"))
```

i am looking for a solution if my "ADD" column have value duplicate then add new column which will show Y & N for duplicate and non Duplicate.

if value is occurring is first_time then "N" and in second and third time and so on will be "Y"

I have tried working like summarise('Duplicate'= n()) but this doesn't work

for eg:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest next approach using `dplyr()` and creating the Yes/No variable:

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>% left_join(data1 %>% 
  group_by(ADD) %>% 
  summarise(N=n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Var=ifelse(N>1,'Yes','No')) %>% 
  select(-N))
```

The output:

```
         ADD Var
1      15366  No
2  ABC_65273  No
3  ABC_87536 Yes
4  ABC_43756  No
5      63854  No
6  ABC_18385  No
7  ABC_87536 Yes
8      11111  No
9  BCG_61773  No
10 ARV_44634  No
11 CAN_46926  No
12 TXA_47268  No
13     64574  No
14 PIP_49229  No
15 BCG_57151  No
16 ARV_49049  No
17 CAN_45493 Yes
18 TXA_49401  No
19     45623  No
20 PIP_41411  No
21 BCG_63402  No
22 CAN_45493 Yes
23 CAN_40584  No
24 TXA_51037  No
25     63523  No
26 PIP_47714  No
27 BCG_57337  No
28 ARV_57727  No
29 CAN_45493 Yes
30 TXA_58079  No
31 PIP_43069  No
```

**Update:** After some details from OP, here another approach:

```
data1 %>% group_by(ADD) %>% mutate(Flag=1:n(),Label=ifelse(Flag==1,'No','Yes')) %>% select(-Flag)
```

Output:

```
         ADD Label
1      15366    No
2  ABC_65273    No
3  ABC_87536    No
4  ABC_43756    No
5      63854    No
6  ABC_18385    No
7  ABC_87536   Yes
8      11111    No
9  BCG_61773    No
10 ARV_44634    No
11 CAN_46926    No
12 TXA_47268    No
13     64574    No
14 PIP_49229    No
15 BCG_57151    No
16 ARV_49049    No
17 CAN_45493    No
18 TXA_49401    No
19     45623    No
20 PIP_41411    No
21 BCG_63402    No
22 CAN_45493   Yes
23 CAN_40584    No
24 TXA_51037    No
25     63523    No
26 PIP_47714    No
27 BCG_57337    No
28 ARV_57727    No
29 CAN_45493   Yes
30 TXA_58079    No
31 PIP_43069    No
```

Where first observation if it has duplicated rows is defined as No.

Comment: this is reducing my actual database, i don't want to reduce database.
i want the database  as it is, but if any value is occurring more than once then it should be Y against it in new column otherwise N.

Comment: @user14176250 I have updated the solution, please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: actually what it is doing is ,lets say we have c(1,2,3,4,5,6,4,7)  so for 4 its giving Y for both 4 but it should yes for second 4, first occurrence should be ignored. after that if 4 occurs many time the should be Y for all 4

Comment: @user14176250 I have added a second update for you. Please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: thanks it also works, also if i want to check spaces before and after values then how can i approach...??
before applying your approach

Comment: @user14176250 Do you mean removing spaces? you can use `trimws()`

Comment: also if there are approx 1m records how it will work fast...???

Comment: @user14176250, it is a base function which is faster you can try `data1$ADD <- trimws(data1$ADD)` before the code for computing the Yes/NO variables.

Comment: no i am saying if records are approx 1M then this code  data1 %>% group_by(ADD) %>% mutate(Flag=1:n(),Label=ifelse(Flag==1,'No','Yes')) %>% select(-Flag)
work fast ....???

Comment: @user14176250 `dplyr` has worked fast with 5 million rows for me in projects where I had to merge several dataframes. So, it should be fast!

Comment: @user14176250 Just assign to a new dataframe like `data2 <- data1 %>% group_by(ADD) %>% mutate(Flag=1:n(),Label=ifelse(Flag==1,'No','Yes')) %>% select(-Flag)`

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicated` function does exactly that:

```
data1$Duplicate <- duplicated(data1$ADD)

data1

#>          ADD Duplicate
#> 1      15366     FALSE
#> 2  ABC_65273     FALSE
#> 3  ABC_87536     FALSE
#> 4  ABC_43756     FALSE
#> 5      63854     FALSE
#> 6  ABC_18385     FALSE
#> 7  ABC_87536      TRUE
#> 8      11111     FALSE
#> 9  BCG_61773     FALSE
#> 10 ARV_44634     FALSE
#> 11 CAN_46926     FALSE
#> 12 TXA_47268     FALSE
#> 13     64574     FALSE
#> 14 PIP_49229     FALSE
#> 15 BCG_57151     FALSE
#> 16 ARV_49049     FALSE
#> 17 CAN_45493     FALSE
#> 18 TXA_49401     FALSE
#> 19     45623     FALSE
#> 20 PIP_41411     FALSE
#> 21 BCG_63402     FALSE
#> 22 CAN_45493      TRUE
#> 23 CAN_40584     FALSE
#> 24 TXA_51037     FALSE
#> 25     63523     FALSE
#> 26 PIP_47714     FALSE
#> 27 BCG_57337     FALSE
#> 28 ARV_57727     FALSE
#> 29 CAN_45493      TRUE
#> 30 TXA_58079     FALSE
#> 31 PIP_43069     FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` to subset the vector `c("N", "Y")` and indicate non duplicated with `N` and duplicated with `Y`.

```
data1$Duplicate <- c("N", "Y")[1+duplicated(data1$ADD)]
data1
#         ADD  Duplicate
#1      15366          N
#2  ABC_65273          N
#3  ABC_87536          N
#4  ABC_43756          N
#5      63854          N
#6  ABC_18385          N
#7  ABC_87536          Y
#8      11111          N
#9  BCG_61773          N
#10 ARV_44634          N
#11 CAN_46926          N
#12 TXA_47268          N
#13     64574          N
#14 PIP_49229          N
#15 BCG_57151          N
#16 ARV_49049          N
#17 CAN_45493          N
#18 TXA_49401          N
#19     45623          N
#20 PIP_41411          N
#21 BCG_63402          N
#22 CAN_45493          Y
#23 CAN_40584          N
#24 TXA_51037          N
#25     63523          N
#26 PIP_47714          N
#27 BCG_57337          N
#28 ARV_57727          N
#29 CAN_45493          Y
#30 TXA_58079          N
#31 PIP_43069          N
```

In case you want ignore white space use `trimws` and to code it with 0 and 1 use a `+`  instead of the vector like:

```
data1$Duplicated <- +(duplicated(trimws(data1$ADD)))
```

Comment: yes it work ,in case if i want 0,1 in place of Y & N, how it will work.
also if i want to check spaces before and after  values  then how can i approach...??

Comment: You can use `trimws` and use `+` instead of the vector. See update.